# How to append authorized_keys on the remote server with id_rsa.pub key

Tags: ssh, public-key, authorized-keys

How to append authorized_keys on the remote server with id_rsa.pub key from the local machine with a single command?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Adding an authorized key could be one-lined this way (use double-quotes so it's interpreted before sent):

```
ssh user@server "echo \"`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`\" >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: Been using `ssh-copy-id` before but this command is great if you have a new public key (eg a new laptop) you want to add to one or a few servers that you already have access to. This allows you to authenticate using keys/settings from `~/.ssh/` but copy a different key. Bravo!

Answer (score 116):

`ssh-copy-id user@remote_server`

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

Comment: This should be he approved answer; the others may be useful if needing to troubleshoot but they are hack-y alternatives to the official recommended method.

Comment: This of course only works if one is authorized to login to host with user/pass alone. Otherwise one will need to find a way to append to authorized_keys manually from within a shell on host system. How one chooses to do this is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: None of these answers work if you do not have access to log into the remote server.

Answer (score 32):

This does the trick:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | (ssh user@host "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
```

Appends the local public key the remote `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @user3132194 parentheses are used for grouping here ...  making sure the >> is on the remote shell

Comment: `ssh user@host "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is a bit shorter and no subshell needed.

Comment: I was trying to add Windows 10 built in openssh keys to my linux host, and this worked `type %userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh user@linux.local "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"`

Answer (score 14):

The `ssh-copy-id` program is the standard way but the key can be appended manually to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@host "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

This does not check if the key already exists and can lead to duplicates.

Answer (score 13):

The most convenient option is the `ssh-copy-id` command. It can append the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. For example:

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i id_rsa.pub username@host
```

Where:

- `-f`: force mode -- copy keys without trying to check if they are already installed
- `-i`: `[identity_file]`

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid some of the quoting with:

```
ssh user@host tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```